# Error communicating with WCF WPF app hosted in Windows Service

Tags: wpf, wcf, windows-services

When there are two different machines access the same WCF service is the error below:

```
Exception throw:
=+=+ BASE EXCEPTION:
APLICATION: mscorlib
ERROR: The socket connection was aborted. This may have
caused by an error processing your message, a timeout
reception exceeded by the remote host or by a problem of network resource
underlying. The local socket timeout was '00: 30:00 '.
CALLSTACK:
Server stack trace:
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32
offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan
timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.Receive(TimeSpan
timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan
timeout, Message& message)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message,
TimeSpan timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway,
ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   in
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg,
IMessage retMsg)
   in
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
msgData, Int32 type)
   in
Evolution.WCF.Contract.IMenuService.GetFullMenu(Int32 userId, Int32 softwareId)
   in
Evolution.CompanyPage.MenuVertical.btn_Menu_Click(Object sender,
RoutedEventArgs e) =+=+ INNER EXCEPTION:
APLICATION: System
ERRO: Was forced to cancel an existing connection by remote host
CALLSTACK:   
in System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   in
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32
offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing) END INNER EXCEPTION =+=+
END BASE EXCEPTION =+=+ =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+ END EXCEPTION
=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+
```

Comment: I can't read spanish, however I can tell you that WCF throws a generic error when it encounters a problem, and the error message given usually does not point to the actual problem. We will probably need more detail than the error message to help you with this (and preferably in English)

Comment: I think it's Portuguese. looks like a socket timeout. double check the address and/or try attaching a debugger to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are having a timeout exception. Try increasing the timeout option of your service.

Also, sometimes you can get this exception if you have a problem with the security related setting of WCF service endpoing. Try disabling it (for testing purposes) and see if you still get the problem. More info about how to disable it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/271b1816-173c-4c76-a4c4-fd9fda4b5e91/).

Comment: This problem occurs only when a second machine tries to use the application. Once the 2nd machine accesses a public method.
Operation is normal when only one machine is involved.

Comment: Okay. The problem occur because I used a static property in server side to do the validation. 
I'll try change the validation for a hash table with the users and passwords of the application. I intend put this into memory, for improve the performance.
Anybody have any tips?